# No cached version of gradle

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin

I am getting this error when syncing gradle. I am pretty new to gradle so can't figure out what is the problem exactly?

> Error:No cached version of com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.10.1
>   available for offline mode.

When I go to `Setting->Gradle`, I have offline mode ticked off and using default gradle wrapper.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

In my case I also had an additional "offline switch" to the one in Gradle.

Go to:

```
File > Settings > Build, Execution, Deployment > Compiler
```

There I've removed the `--offline` in `Command-line Options`.
Earlier I was trying to speed up Android Studio a bit and this was one of the changes I had made.

Everything was fine after a restart then (and I have re-enabled both offline parts).

Comment: and if I don't want to disable offline?

Comment: You can disable it temporarily and enable it again later.

Answer (score 55):

I have Android Studio 3.6 Beta 1, so there is no checkBox `offline mode` in Gradle settings.

If somebody can't find it as well, here is the answer:

1. Ctrl + Shift + "A"
2. Type `Gradle`, then click `Enter`

[image: You can toggle offline mode now]

Comment: This should have been helpful, but for some reason it didn't alter the behavior. 

For me it started immediately after updating the A.Studio. (191.601...-> 192.620...) I uninstalled and installed the latest version and it continued failing, but it looks like blasting user settings on installation fixed it. (I uninstalled and installed twice, here, if that's unclear)

This suggests that updating can mangle some relevant user settings, but I don't know enough about Gradle, yet, to work out the specifics.

Answer (score 28):

If you have **Android Studio 3.6**(Stable). You can **switch** between **cached version** and **online version** of gradle.

Look at the **right side** of the Android studio, you will see **gradle** tab. Click on it.

[image]

[image]

**If you cannot see gradle tab then**

[image]

Answer (score 6):

This problem occurs, if you have offline mode switched on in your IDE and let the IDE upgrade your build file to use 0.10.1 of the gradle plugin (that is needed for the new AS version. Since you have never build with this version, it cannot be found in the offline cache.

Go to File->Settings->Gradle (under Project Settings on the top) and disable the check in front of Offline Work (Section 'Global Gradle settings' at the bottom).
Now it can download the version with the next build and afterwards you are free to use offline mode again, if you wish so.

Answer (score 4):

**Disable offline mode** to solve this error.

In Android studio:

`File -> Other Settings -> Default Settings -> Build,Execution,Deployment -> Build Tools -> Gradle`

Then **uncheck** `Offline work` and sync again.

Hope your issue will resolved.

Answer (score 4):

I'm using Android Studio 3.6.3 
I did not find the `offline work` option in `Settings`

Select Gradle in `View > ToolWindows > Gradle` 
or search Gradle on `CTRL + SHIFT + A`

There you can find a `Toggle Offline Mode` Button

[image: Toggle Offline Mode Button in Gradle]

Answer (score 4):

From Android Studio 4.1 there is a new location of the toggle offline mode.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

In Android Studio 3.6 (or above) Click on the **Gradle Button** Which is at right side, it will open up small window, here click on the “***Toggle Offline Mode***” icon for enable or disable toggle. See below image for reference.

- Shortcut key can also be set from settings as one is being shewn in image below that I've set.

[image: Gradle Side menu with Offline toggle button]

Answer (score 2):

You can toggle offline mode by opening the Gradle panel on your right, and click the following button :
[image]

Answer (score 2):

I faced the same issue when I updated my old version to **Android Studio 4.0**.
I solved it this way first of all. Go To
`File -> Settings -> Appearance & Behavior -> System Settings -> HTTP Proxy`
and select the option **Auto-detect proxy settings** and then click **OK** as shown in the picture below

[Select Auto-detect proxy settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6XPW8.png)

After that go to Gradle window in the right-side tool window and disable the **Toggle Offline Mode** as shown in the picture below

[Disable Gradle offline mode](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kee5G.png)

At the end sync the gradle by hitting the Try again button at the top of the code window

[Sync Gradle again](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zRKXl.png)

When you click on Try again it will pop the proxy window you just need to click on the Yes button and don't change anything and that's it. Your issue will be fixed.

Answer (score 1):

I thought I should post the latest update on where you should be able to find the option to disable your Offline Work in IntelliJ.

It's under your Preferences -> Build, Execution, Deployment

Uncheck Offline work and you should be fine.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I’ve also encountered this issue and from Android Studio 3.6 the setting changed and can be found in another window. As stated here:

> New location to toggle Gradle's offline mode To enable or disable Gradle's offline mode, first select View > Tool Windows > Gradle from the menu bar. Then, near the top of the Gradle window, click Toggle Offline Mode Gradle offline button in the Gradle panel.

Here are the release notes: https://developer.android.com/studio/releases/#3.6-gradle-offline-ui

Answer (score 1):

From Android 3.6 below is the path to change the offline mode.

New location to toggle Gradle's offline mode To enable or disable Gradle's offline mode, first select View > Tool Windows > Gradle from the menu bar. Then, near the top of the Gradle window, click Toggle Offline Mode Gradle offline button in the Gradle panel..

Answer (score 1):

I have different solutions since none of the above solution worked for me I don't know why (in macOS)

To disabled the offline mode since com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:17.1.0 No cached version available for offline mode

**STEP: 1** Just make changes like

com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:17.1.1 in the gradle

**STEP: 2** Which will pop Sync Now option

press Sync Now

**STEP: 3** then in your build will appear (Disable offline mode and Sync)

Press Disabled offline mode and Sync and the offline mode will be disabled

**STEP: 4** Change com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:17.1.1 to com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:17.1.0 then Sync again

It worked for me hope it helps you

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem in Android Studio v3.2.1.

This is working for me.

I updated Gradle version in **build.gradle**

```
 dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.2.1'//same as Android Studio vesion           
 }
```

and changed **distributionUrl** in **gradle-wrapper.properties**

```
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-4.4-all.zip
```

to

```
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-4.6-all.zip
```

Answer (score 0):

[image]In newer versions of android studio offline mode toggle button can be found here.[image]

You can even customize to a shortcut in keymap if necessary. Just search 'offline mode' in **Settingings** -> **Keymap**

Answer (score 0):

If the Android Studio Settings do not work (as with me)
You can also try to set `startParameter.isOffline=false` in the `settings.gradle` file.
Then Clean the project and Build again.