# Gradle Failed to Build

Tags: android, gradle

[image: There Errors I am seeing]
[image: This is what my app.gradle looks like]

Literally, I have tried every suggested solution online to this problem; yet, the error still persists.

Comment: Just try to connect to internet and then build the gradle

Comment: Did you double check you don't have offline mode enabled in settings?

Comment: Btw, you'd better post here code instead of screenshots, it's easier to copy.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [No cached version of gradle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24144598/no-cached-version-of-gradle)

Comment: i was faced same and solution is :-https://stackoverflow.com/a/47829739/3974530

Comment: Thanks guys, seem all I needed to do was just to disable offline mood. Problem resolved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check you don't have offline work enabled in your ***Build, Execution, Deployment > Gradle*** settings.

[image: Gradle Settings]

Comment: Thanks! It worked!