# Gradle sync failed: No cached version available for offline mode

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

I have two separated computers, the first having an internet access where the other one doesn't have. I used the one with internet access to install android studio build my android application where gradle caches all required dependencies. Then I managed to move the application along with the android studio and the `.gradle` folder into the offline pc, then setting `GRADLE_HOME` to the `.gradle` directory. I'd also checked `offline mode` in the android gradle setting of my project. But gradle still doesn't find its cached dependencies, saying:

```
Gradle sync failed: Could not download org.eclipse.jgit.jar ...: No cached version available for offline mode
```

Note that the above required dependency is already exist in the gradle cache.

Comment: refer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22607661/no-cached-version-of-com-android-tools-buildgradle0-9-1-available-for-offline

Comment: there is a .gradle folder in `C:\Users\$your_user_name\.gradle`. Copy that also.

Comment: Thanks, but nor of the suggested answers work for me. besides, i have no .gradle folder in my user directory because i managed to change GRADLE_HOME on the online machine

Comment: Check this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24144598/no-cached-version-of-gradle

Comment: sorry but this doesn't work either

Comment: This project was in Eclipse project ?

Comment: no it is an android studio one

Comment: Uncheck offline mode sync your project,then try again ,if it still doesn't work then click Invalidate and Restart.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seams like `gradle` maps its cached dependencies using their absolute path, so moving `.gradle` directory into another pc will not work if the full path of the parent differs between the two computers. to solve the problem i managed to change the path of my `gradle` home on the online pc into **"C:\Program Files\android.gradle"** by setting the environment variable **GRADLE_USER_HOME** to that path. Then started android studio and built my application to cache dependencies. After that i was able to successfully copy `.gradle` folder from the online machine into the offline one by placing it in the same path as the online machine `gradle` path and pointing to that path through the EV **GRADLE_USER_HOME**.