# android studio 3.6.2-6040484 available for offline mode

Tags: android

i update Android studio yesterday ( 3-4-2020),i get this error :

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':app:mergeDebugResources'.

  > Could not resolve all files for configuration ':app:_internal_aapt2_binary'.
  >   Could not resolve com.android.tools.build:aapt2:3.6.2-6040484.
  >    Required by:
  >        project :app
  >   No cached version of com.android.tools.build:aapt2:3.6.2-6040484 available for offline mode.
  >   No cached version of com.android.tools.build:aapt2:3.6.2-6040484 available for offline mode.

any one can help,
thanks

Comment: It says offline mode. Are you offline or have enabled offline mode from the Android Studio menus? The issue seems to be that a file cannot be downloaded because of offline mode.

Answer (score 1):

go to ->File -> project structures -> if any suggestions ->update and compile all->apply ->ok  and disable offline mode

Answer (score 0):

It's an internet connection problem. it happens to me from time to time. I usually use a VPN to fix it.
and make sure your Gradle setting is not in offline mode.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it!
Earlier, after I set up everything on my Android Studio, I switched the Gradle Compiler work mode to *--offline* in Command-line Options in Settings:

`File > Settings > Build, Execution, Deployment > Compiler`

This solved the issue. Right after I solved it, I saw a [similar solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24144598/no-cached-version-of-gradle) and concluded that copy pasting the problem from build log may not always work, you should read it attentively, stop and think, and make a conscious search.

Let me know if it solves your problem too, if not we will try to come up with something else.

Answer (score 0):

Toogle the offline mode in the upper right section. This should solve your problem

Answer (score 0):

just go to the gradle section on top right corner, and switch off 'Toggle Offline Mode' (on the top toolbar) and you are good to go