# Could not resolve com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.1.1

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle, gradle-plugin

I'm facing the below error for the last 3 days, I tried everything to get rid of this error. I've even uninstalled android studio completely by following [How to uninstall android studio completely](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39953495/how-to-completely-uninstall-android-studio-from-windowsv10) and installed it again but the error is still there.

In possible suggestions, the android studio says `Disable offline mode and rerun the build` but the offline mode is already disabled.

I tried the following conversations:

1. [No cached version of gradle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24144598/no-cached-version-of-gradle): the answers available in this question is all about turning the toggle Gradle offline and after trying the error is still there.
2. [What is "disable offline mode" and "disable gradle offline" mode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64635762/what-is-disable-offline-mode-and-disable-gradle-offline-mode-and-this-settin)

> After looking at the answers to the above questions people appreciate
> that their problem has been solved but Idk what's wrong with my side.

**Is there another option other than already available answers?**

[image]

Comment: I don't see 7.1.1. on Google official website changeling but I can see 7.1.0 https://developer.android.com/studio/releases/gradle-plugin. Check on this website and try to use that Gradle version

Comment: @AsthaGarg IDE suggests `A newer version of com.android.tools.build:gradle than 7.1.0 is available: 7.1.1`

Comment: Latest plugin version is 7.2 and required Gradle version of this is 7.3+. Check once with required gradle version this. Just refer the Gradle official site for any ref. Let me know if it helps

Comment: Do you mean this one? https://docs.gradle.org/7.1.1/release-notes.html#upgrade-instructions

Comment: https://developer.android.com/studio/releases/gradle-plugin?buildsystem=ndk-build#updating-gradle this

Comment: @ShoaibKhalid I don't think it's about offline/online mode, since studio is unable to resolve/find the Gradle version you are giving it's showing this error

Comment: @AsthaGarg i've `gradle-version 7.2` in `gradle-wrapper.properties` and `com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.1.1` in `build.gradle(project)`. I think its okay, the only problem is with offline mode, i honestly don't whats going wrong.

Comment: which android studio version are you using?

Comment: @AsthaGarg I was using Arctic fox after facing this problem I updated to bumblebee, the latest one but the error is still there.

Comment: Ya it's quite strange because I tried with same Gradle configuration are yours and it's working fine for me. Have you tried Invalidate cache and restart, sometimes it helps unexpectedly ? Secondly, try creating a sample project with same configuration see if it works

Comment: @AsthaGarg can you please share your gradle.build files code in github gist?

Comment: @ShoaibKhalid https://github.com/asthagarg2428/Gradle-version-Check/blob/main/build.gradle (I created a Blank Activity project hence nothing much in grade file but yes the code is compilable)